# Is there a way to conditionaly format a cell based on 2 columns, where 1 column determines the comparator of the other?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up an excel sheet where there are 2 relevant columns. In column 1 there are 1 of 3 possible text entries and the other column is a number. Based on the text in column 1, I want to choose what to compare column 2 against. So for example

```
if A1.value = "X1" then I want the comparison "B1.value > .1" 
if A1.value = "X2" then I want the comparison "B1.value < -.2"
if A1.value = "X3" then I want the comparison "B1.value >.101"
```

Based on the B1.value comparison returning TRUE I want to highlight the cell. The highlighting would be the same for each possible text value

I have tried using traditional conditional formatting using the write your own formula block using

```
=IFS(AND($A1 = "X1", B1 >.1),1,AND($A1 = "X2", B1 <.2),1,AND($A1 = "X3", B1 >.101))
```

That did not work, because the B1 did not transfer across all the selected cells. So the formula was the same for cell B1 as it was for C1. Is there a good way to accomplish this using VBA macros?

Comment: Just use the `AND` function in your conditional format formula. The `IF` is redundant here. Your explanation is a little confusing. Can you give a screen shot of some examples and show how you want them highlighted?

Comment: What about the other two possible text values in A1? Do you want to hightlight the cell the same way for all 5 possibilities?

Comment: Something like `If A1.value = "X1" And B1.value > .1 then...` for your options, but with no data example, it's just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the sample data I used:

[image]

With this conditional formatting rule:

```
=OR(AND($A1="X1",$B1>0.1),AND($A1="X2",$B1<-0.2),AND($A1="X3",$B1>0.101))
```

On range:

```
=$A$1:$B$9
```

Simply add more `AND` statement for the missing two text values in column A

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a combination of `AND` and `OR` in your formula.
You want to highlight something if
  A1 = "X1" **AND** B1 > 0.01
**OR**
  A1 = "X2" **AND** B1 < -0.2
**OR**
  A1 = "X3" **AND** B1 < 0.101

So the formula for conditional formatting would be

```
=OR(AND($A1="X1",$B1>0.1),AND($A1="X2",$B1<-0.1),AND($A1="X3",$B1>0.101))
```